# Pass a function to kendo UI chart "data" element

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Hi I am trying to display some data in a kendo UI bar chart , the data comes from an ASP.NET MVC action that returns json data.
Is it possible to pass a function to a kendo UI **data** element like the following ?

```
 series: [{
        name: "Oddo Avenir Euro CI-EUR",
        data: GetFundPerfCalendSP,
        border: {
        width: 0
        }
```

The function :

```
function GetFundPerfCalendSP(){
      $(document).ready(function(){
      var data;
      var value = $("#idProduitSP").text();
      var bechmarkArray = new Array();
      var SpArray = new Array();
      console.log(value);     
      $.ajax({ 
      url:'../controllerName/actionname',
      type:'POST',
      datatype:'json',
      data:{
      idProduitSP:value
      },
      success :function(result)   
      data = result;   
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      SpArray.push(data[i].PerformanceSP*100);    
      }
      console.log(SpArray);
      return SpArray;
      },
      error:function(error){
      console.log("ajax request failed");
      }
      });
      });
      }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the transport property of the dataSource: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport

Comment: Yes , the problems is that I need to make that Ajax request from the client side because I am retrieving and ID from anHtml Element that will be sent to the MVC action that will provide the data to the chart.

Comment: So instead of putting the function in the data, just build the chart in the success callback of the AJAX.